# How to use the Table Storage Service in Windows 8 App using Javascript

Tags: windows-8, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am working on a Windows 8 App using JavaScript. I want to use the Azure table storage as my database as the data I am storing is only a key-value pair. I do not find any link on Azure site for the same. Can I use Azure table storage service to connect with my app using javascript?

Comment: Does each user of your app have a storage account? If not, do you intend to give all of them the keys to your storage account?

Comment: The users do not have a storage account and I would like to embed the keys in the app itself. Is that a good practice?

Comment: Giving away the keys to your storage account is not a good practice. Anyone who has your keys could delete all your data, upload their own private DVD collection, etc. You really need to keep your keys on the server and expose a web service to your app.

Comment: Hmm..Does that mean we need to host a mobile service or we should create a web service that uses Table Storage to expose data and perform CRUD operation. I believe, a mobile service uses SQL server and cannot use Table storage. Please confirm.

Comment: You can use Mobile Services for this, since it supports the full Node.js storage library, but I'm not sure it's the best fit. A simple web service is probably easiest.

Comment: Can Mobile services use Storage device instead of SQL server? I could not find one when creating a mobile service in my azure panel.

Comment: Yes, as I said, Mobile Services supports the full Node.js storage library. But it's going to be awkward... you'll need SQL tables that you'll essentially never be using. It's not a great way to build this.

Comment: @smarx Thank you for all your inputs:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, please download the widows.azure.storage.winmd at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/05/windows-azure-storage-client-library-for-windows-runtime.aspx
Although I haven't work it out, but I think it's a possible way, because I can use it in my C#/xmal store app.

Mobile service is another choice, but I think it's not a good choice because it's hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks. I will chk this out!